# How to pass a boolean and verify a boolen in an if statement?

Tags: java

OK I'm on the final part of my game, then I will invite you all to play. Its not perfect by no means, but its a huge milestone in my Java progress.
So in my code I'm calling my puzzle class to verify if the solution given by the user `equalsIgnoreCase` of the private variable solution provided in the puzzle class. If they match it returns true, else, it returns false. On the tester, if I get the true value returned, it should print I was right and if it returns false I get it wrong.
The problem is that I type it in right, but it tells me I'm wrong. Why?

puzzle:

```
    public boolean solvePuzzle(String answer)
    {
        if(this.solution.equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

puzzletester:

```
    if(choice==2)
   {
        System.out.println("Please solve the puzzle");
        input.nextLine();
        String answer=input.next();
        answer=answer.toUpperCase();
        game.solvePuzzle(answer);

        if(game.solvePuzzle(answer)==true)
        {
        System.out.println("That is correct");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("You are wrong");
        }
        }


        }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code, where you are facing problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the statement `solution.equalsIgnoreCase(solution);` in `guessLetter`?

Comment: Just a note: your solvePuzzle method can be written as: `return this.solution.equalsIgnoreCase(solution);`. This test: `if(game.solvePuzzle(solution)==true)` can be written as `if (game.solvePuzzle(solution))`. A boolean expression is of type boolean already. No need to compare the boolean to true to get a boolean.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'm trying to compare the variable solution (variable entered by the user) to the instance variable used in the puzzle class (solution).

Comment: @PremGenError Whats not relevant about this code? Are you just wanting the methods where the problem lies. I just thought that giving you the whole code would help understand the program better.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok I tried your idea and your right about the way its written, however it doesn't solve the problem of making the correct solution true.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote "Just a note" and posted it as a comment. I don't know the solution, and I'm not even sure I know what the problem is. Use a debugger to step through the program line by line, and look at the values of the variables.

Comment: @JBNizet I use eclipse to compile the code. I'm not sure how to use the debugger. Got any tips?

Comment: @SkyVar the thing is its really hard when you see lotta code to find the problem. i would re produce your problem for smaller test case, so that it'd easy for everyone to understand your problem quickly ..:)

Comment: Ok cleaned up the code to a nice 2 part section. Hopefully thats easier to read.

Comment: @SkyVar, that statement compares a string to itself and then does nothing with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Hint to the solution: Read carefully the javadoc of the Scanner class, and especially the part explaining what the default delimiter is, as well as the documentation of the `next()` method. Now look at what the solution is, and ask yourself if it could have a relationship with what the default delimiter is.

To confirm, choose another solution and see if it changes something. Also print the values of the variables you compare to see what they actually contain, or learn to use the Eclipse debugger. It's not so hard, and I'm sure Eclipse has a help page about it.

Comment: changed next() to nextLine().
Gold Star sir! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually just using Scanner, which by default deliminates using whitespace. You need to call the useDelimiter() method to set it up correctly. You could use a BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```